# I don't have a review-audit for a while already. Why?

Tags: discussion, review-audit

I don't have a review-audit for a while already. Why? I love review-audits, because when it said I passed, I am happy. But I think there should be an audit about per 10 reviews, but I still don't receive an audit. Actually how frequent is a audit?

Edit: Yeah I've got an audit! [image: :)]

Comment: Never thought we'd have an audit junkie...

Comment: "Test items in review queues that are designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills, while nudging more experienced users that don't seem to be paying close attention to what they're reviewing." what a review audit is for...

Comment: You're reviewing almost exclusively First Posts. Try reviewing some of the Close queue.

Comment: they can't they need about double their rep @AlexanderGruber

Comment: Why does this have 6 downvotes?! I mean, its a valid question, whatever you think of the motivation.

Comment: downvotes mean disagreement on meta.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I am aware of this. However, there is no opinion being offered here; there is nothing to disagree with!

Comment: sure there is, if we all get review audits more often or not...

Comment: [Review Audit FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work), you should [have been so lucky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181417/282094). I haven't received a Review Audit in several months, while I don't do many reviews (except on our main Meta, where we are sometimes asked about our reviews by a person) I don't miss the audits. Try Stack Overflow if you enjoy seeing them, IMO that's where there are the most.